# How to inject token to the dio provider from Riverpod StateNotifierProvider?

Tags: riverpod, riverpod-generator, riverpod-annotation

Using `riverpod_generator`.

How can I inject JWT token to the auth header in Dio:

```
@riverpod
Dio dio(DioRef ref) => Dio();

@riverpod
ITodoDatasource todoApiService(TodoApiServiceRef ref) {
  Dio dio = ref.watch(dioProvider);
  return TodoApiService(dio);
}

@riverpod
ITodoRepository todoRepository(TodoRepositoryRef ref) {
  ITodoDatasource todoApiService = ref.watch(todoApiServiceProvider);
  return TodoApiRepository(todoApiService);
}
```